# Is bool actually blittable in .NET 8?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Microsoft's [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/best-practices#blittable-types-when-runtime-marshalling-is-enabled) is quite clear that `bool` is not blittable. The documentation also says that:

> You can see if a type is blittable or contains blittable contents by attempting to create a pinned `GCHandle`. If the type isn't a string or considered blittable, `GCHandle.Alloc` will throw an `ArgumentException`.

So why doesn't the following code throw an exception for me?

```
$ cat Program.cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
GCHandle.Alloc(new bool(), GCHandleType.Pinned).Free();

$ dotnet run

$ dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:           8.0.200
 Commit:            438cab6a9d
 Workload version:  8.0.200-manifests.cdf2cc8e

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  22.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.200/

.NET workloads installed:
There are no installed workloads to display.

Host:
  Version:      8.0.2
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       1381d5ebd2

.NET SDKs installed:
  8.0.200 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.2 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.2 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

Comment: C doesn't define a `bool` type. Usually `(int)0` is considered false, and all other values considered true. So what if your native code returns `(int)3`? How should that be marshalled back to C#?

Comment: `GCHandle.Alloc` calls the internal `Marshal.IsPinnable` which has different implementations per runtime. Though the implementation was relaxed in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commit/fc303bb0f055e7d6adf9be5a53d4369b90669799 to only check for pointers.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman that's not true at all. C99 has `_Bool` and C23 has `bool`

Comment: So say that, for whatever reason, .NET 8 currently treats bool as blittable but the documentation currently states that it isn't. So you build something that relies upon this *undocumented* behaviour and then everything might break at any future time if it has to become unblittable again. Why would you choose to write software like this? If you want guarantees, rely on the documentation, not the current behaviour of one implementation.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The documentation might be wrong or incomplete. That's what this question is trying to ascertain.

Comment: Yeah, I'd raise an issue against the documentation page (https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/main/docs/standard/native-interop/best-practices.md) pointing out the inconsistency and asking for clarification.

Comment: Submitted https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/39654